# Cannot Load External JS File on HTML file

Tags: javascript, magento-1, html, package, external-script

Decided to use echarts.js for a specific page in my site. Tried to download the package file on my server and then I tried to include it using a script tag. However, when I open the page I get a thousand different errors for it and not an exact cause for my error.

How can I include an external javascript file in my HTML and make it available or even run on load?

Comment: Which Magento version? Magento 1 and Magento 2.x will have different answers. Also, please, post your errors.

Comment: I think its Magento 1. Since the site is migrating to magento 2 in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information for anybody to be able to help you. What are the errors you're seeing, how did you add the js?

Comment: I added the JS by simply including it in a script tag at the end of my HTML file. I will copy the errors by tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can add js using layout as below:

By utilizing `default_head_blocks.xml` in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>

        <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

**Option 2:**

by utilizing `requirejs-config.js` in your themes or custom module

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
          echarts : 'Magento_Theme/js/echarts.js'
     }
    }
};
```

You can include in phtml by utilizing below code

```
require([ 'jquery' , 'echarts'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
        //custom js code goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a Magento 1 specific answer, I'll ask the OP what Magento version he's using.